# How to disable UINavigationController?

Tags: iphone

I have a navigation controller-based app in which I would like to temporarily disable the navigation controller (top left button) at a certain point in the app so that the user can't get out of the view while I'm uploading a file. Is there a way to disable the "back" button so that users can't get out of the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could hide the navigation bar entirely with

```
- (void)setNavigationBarHidden:animated:
```

in the appropriate views.

I don't know of an Apple-approved way to disable or otherwise interact with the back button.

Answer (score 0):

In the view controller pushing into the view where you want to hide the back button (NOT in the view controller where you want the back button hidden), do:

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```